# How to initialize Materializecss form elements at run time?

Tags: materialize

I am adding form input elements at runtime, and i am using materializecss. text inputs do not render properly and I am guessing that they need to be initialized in javascript same as select or paralax. ex: `('.parallax').parallax(); , $(".select").material_select();`
Is there an equivelent for form inputs for instance something like?
`$('.parallax').material_input();`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a solution that works for me: `Materialize.updateTextFields();`